# Can we always choose a gauge in GR in which time is constant?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, time, gauge

In General relativity the metric describes the curvature of 4D space-time. But due to diffeomorphism invariance, many metrics describe the same physics.

Can we always choose a metric such that we can foliate space-time into slices which have curvature but time runs constantly between slices. So that $g_{00}=1$ and $g_{0i}=0$.

So that knowing the curvature of the space slice is all we need to know.

In other words can we always write metrics in terms of space curvature without time curvature. So it is a theory in which the curvature of 3-space changes with time.

Comment: 1. Not all Lorentzian manifolds can be foliated, those that can are called [globally hyperbolic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_hyperbolic_manifold). 2. Have you thought of the much simpler question whether a single arbitrary symmetric 4x4 matrix can be brought into the form you desire? A naive counting of the number of independent parameters would suggest that this is impossible - do you have any reason to believe this should work at all?

Comment: @ACuriousMind can you expand on the idea of foliation in GR? I.e. other S.E questions or book and paper references?

Comment: Why? A coordinate transformation has 4 degrees of freedom and one wants to fix 4 degrees of freedom. So naively I would guess it works.

Comment: @Dan Yand Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Locally yes. And by locally, I mean "in an open domain", not just infinitesimally.

To see this consider a spacelike hypersurface $\Sigma$, equipped with local coordinates $\xi^a$. Let $n^\mu$ be the future-directed unit normal field to $\Sigma$. Now, given an initial point and an initial vector, the geodesic equation has unique solutions, but there is no guarantee that they are indefinitely extendible. At a point $x\in\Sigma$ let $\gamma(\lambda)$ be the geodesic with initial velocity $n^\mu(x)$.

If the coordinates of $x\in\Sigma$ are $\xi^1,...,\xi^n$, then we should assign to the point $\gamma(\lambda)$ the coordinates $(\lambda,\xi^1,...,\xi^n)$.

It is not difficult to see that there is at least an open neighborhood of the $n-1$ dimensional coordinate domain on $\Sigma$ in which this is a well-defined coordinate system. It can also be seen that as long as this construct is well defined, the $\lambda$ coordinate will remain orthogonal to the $\xi$ coordinates.

The metric in this coordinate system has components $g_{00}=g_{\mu\nu}n^\mu n^\nu=-1$, $g_{0a}=g_{\mu\nu}n^\mu(\partial_a)^\nu=0$, so it is in required form.

This construction is referred to as Gaussian normal coordinates.